# MAUI Button staying pressed after awaiting Shell.Current.GoToAsync()

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

In my MAUI app I am navigating between two pages, the main page and add page.

I am using `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync()` in a Command on the ViewModel that the Button calls. However, when I click the Button, it stays grayed out. It navigates to the correct page, but when I return to the page it is still grayed out. If I right click the Button it fixes this and is no longer grayed out. If I take the `await` away or make it not async both fix the issue too.

[image: MainPage before button press]
[image: AddPage before return button press]
[image: Main page after button press and returned from add page]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:ButtonTest"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:MainPageViewModel"
             x:Class="ButtonTest.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="AddPage"
                Command="{Binding GoAddPageCommand}"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

```cs
namespace ButtonTest;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int count = 0;

    public MainPage(MainPageViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext= vm;
    }

    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count++;

        if (count == 1)
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
        else
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

        SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
    }
}
```

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ButtonTest
{
    public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [RelayCommand]
        public async Task GoAddPage()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//AddPage");
        }
    } 
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:ButtonTest"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:AddPageViewModel"
             x:Class="ButtonTest.AddPage"
             Title="AddPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="MainPage"
                Command="{Binding GoMainPageCommand}"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ButtonTest
{
    public partial class AddPageViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [RelayCommand]
        public async Task GoMainPage()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//MainPage");
        }
    }
}
```

Appshell.xaml

```
<Shell
    x:Class="ButtonTest.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ButtonTest"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <ShellContent
        Title="MainPage"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />

    

</Shell>
```

AppShell.xaml.cs

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute($"{nameof(MainPage)}", typeof(MainPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute($"{nameof(AddPage)}", typeof(AddPage));

    }
}
```

I would think that after Button press it would return to the normal color. I tried removing `async` or not returning a `Task` and that works fine as expected. How do you deal with asynchronous Commands and Buttons?

Comment: Please do NOT post code as images

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `[RelayCommand]` attribute to auto-generate a `Command` for a method, it depends on the method's return type and signature what type of `Command` will be generated.

### 1. RelayCommand

When your method has a `void` return type, then a `RelayCommand` is generated for you under the hood:

```cs
[RelayCommand]
private void DoSomething()
{
    //e.g.
    Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//AddPage");
}
```

Here, a `RelayCommand` will be generated and since the method is `void`, its execution can't be awaited and it runs synchronously. Therefore, the Command returns immediately and the Button is enabled again right-away.

### 2. AsyncRelayCommand

When your method is of return type `async Task` on the other hand, it will create an `AsyncRelayCommand` under the hood:

```cs
[RelayCommand]
private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    //e.g.
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//MainPage");
}
```

There are a few key differences here:

1. An `AsyncRelayCommand` awaits the execution of the Task
2. While awaiting the execution, the `IsRunning` flag of the `AsyncRelayCommand` will be set to `true`
3. Buttons in MAUI recognize `AsyncRelayCommands` and get disabled while the `IsRunning` flag is `true`, which is not the case for the synchronous `RelayCommand`

In this case, your Button stays disabled until the `Shell.Current.GoToAsync();` call finishes execution. That may take a long time, depending on what's going on in your app.

### Quick fix

Unless you need to specifically wait for the navigation call, you could just change the method signature to return `void` instead of a `Task` like in section 1 above. *Note that this means your method won't be awaitable when called directly.*

### General remarks

I recommend not performing navigation directly inside ViewModels. Personally, I think it's better to hide navigation behind an interface or delegate it to a View's code behind. That way, the ViewModel stays clean and testable.

As to why the Button never returns to its active color, there may be a bug, although I've yet to encounter that. For me, it worked fine so far in my MAUI applications. However, I always delegate navigation to my Views or to a helper class outside of my ViewModels.

Comment: I did try to move the command into the View and I still had the same issue. Interestingly if I register the route in the AppShell.cs for the AddPage, that button works as expected and returns to the proper color. 

```Routing.RegisterRoute($"{nameof(AddPage)}", typeof(AddPage));```

Unfortunately, you have to have one registered in the shellcontent xaml it seems, so I cant fix my problem by registering in the cs file for both.

I also see that I could return void or not await, but I was told to ALWAYS await in every situation if using async.

Comment: "Unfortunately, you have to have one registered in the shellcontent xaml it seems" - what is that supposed to mean? You can and should always register your routes in AppShell.xaml.cs. It's not mandatory for the ones that are part of Shell's view hierarchy (meaning they're defined as `ShellContent` elements in AppShell.xaml), but it should be possible nevertheless. Can you show your AppShell.xaml and AppShell.xaml.cs and add them to the **question**?

Comment: Ok I updated the question with those files. I didnt know you do both places only that you had to at least have one in the AppShell.xaml. I am still learning about routing. The issue still persists after adding it to the AppShell.xaml.cs for the (MainPage). However, the route not in the AppShell.xaml (addpage) but in the AppShell.xaml.cs button works as expected if I navigate back to it after clicking, if I put it in the AppShell.xaml then it no longer works as expected and is grayed out when I come back to the page.

Answer (score 0):

By default, an async RelayCommand will disable the button until the command's Task completes. The behaviour you've described here indicates that `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync()` does not complete, which is likely a bug. You can verify this by placing a breakpoint right after `GoToAsync()` and checking whether it is hit after the AddPage is shown.

Comment: I set the break point after the GoToAsync Call and it hits it before it navigates to the page, if I continue then it navigates to the page

Answer (score 0):

You can change the method to the codes below.

```
 public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [RelayCommand]
        public static void GoAddPage()
        {
            Shell.Current.GoToAsync("add");
        }
    }
```

Using the async method make the button must wait, so it can not finish the task until you turn it back to the main thread. So this is why the color can not be changed back. You can use the static method.

Comment: It's not a color change per sé, the button gets disabled while the Task hasn't completed. It would be useful to the OP to understand why this happens and why your solution may solve the issue.

Comment: I did see this is an option but was told it is bad to not await async calls like GoToAsync() so I am trying to find another way around it.

Comment: I have the same problem, maybe you should open an issue on github